# Combine 2 PHFetchResults together

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

New to Swift and iOS development. Can someone tell me how I can combine the results of two calls to PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType? Specifically I'm trying to get a single list that contains both the standard albums and the smart albums in one list.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a best practice or whatever, but I needed to do something like this today and the following appears to work:

```
@property NSMutableArray<PHAssetCollection *> *collections;

...

/* Get albums of interest */
PHFetchResult *albums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype: ... options: ...];
/* Get smart albums of interest (in my case, the Camera Roll) */
PHFetchResult *cameraRoll = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options: ...];
/* Load albums into collections member */
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < albums.count; ++i)
    [self.collections addObject:[albums objectAtIndex:i]];
/* Load Camera Roll into collections member */
[self.collections addObject:[cameraRoll firstObject]];
```

Just remember to initialize your collections member before adding objects to it.

Comment: The question mentions Swift, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers: options: api of PHAsset.
First get an album:

```
PHFetchResult *album = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype: ... options: ...];
```

Loop through it:

```
for (PHAsset *asset in album) {     
    [self.localIDList addObject:asset.localIdentifier];
}
```

Use this for each album you need. And finally...

```
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:self.localIDList options:nil];
```

Comment: Would this give me a list of the albums, or a list of the assets in the albums? Specifically I'm after a single-list that contains all the albums, not the assets.

Comment: list of assets in the albums. Also, if you have same items in multiple albums then it will discard duplicated ones.